# Angular Material Sorting a number assending doesn't work

Tags: angular, sorting, angular-material2

I am currently following the course "Angular Material" by Ajden on PluralSight and I am facing some weird behaviour with the sorting which on used with a table is not working completely. In the course, 3 columns are shown, the first column contains numbers and when I try to sort that column, nothing happens, the numbers stays in a assending way presented. When I sort the second column, which is a text column, the sorting works fine, asscending as well as descending. When I try to sort the number column again after I sorted the text column, the sorting is applied to the number column but always ascending, never descending. Am I missing something in my code or is this perhaps a bug in angular material? I am using the newest versions of Angular and Angular Material because I want to learn it that way.

This is the code I have so far related to the sorting:

**The number sorting**

```
<mat-form-field>
    <input matInput (keyup)="applyFilter($event.target.value)" placeholder="Filter"> </mat-form-field>

<table mat-table matSort [dataSource]="dataSource">

    <!-- Position Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="position">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>No.</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let note"> {{note.id}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Name Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="title">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Title</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let note"> {{note.title}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Date Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="date">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Date</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let note"> {{note.date | date: 'd LLLL yyyy'}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr> </table>

<mat-paginator [pageSize]="2" [pageSizeOptions]="[1, 2, 5]" showFirstLastButtons></mat-paginator>
```

**Linking the sort element to the datasource**

```
@ViewChild(MatSort) 
sort: MatSort;

ngAfterContentInit(): void {
    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Note>(this.notes);
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
}
```

I also put the code I have so far in a git repository, which can be found [here](https://github.com/Cornelis83/ps-angular-material)

Comment: Your code is having issues. Can you please fix those? You can check errors in the browser console or terminal window.

Comment: Can you tell which issues you are facing? Cause when I execute ng serve in my command window, it is running fine and I am not having any errors in my browser console. Also ng build is running successful without any errors.

Comment: Are you sure that you have pushed all of your changes to git? Try to run on stackblitz : https://stackblitz.com/github/Cornelis83/ps-angular-material. Below are the errors : ```ERROR in ./src/app/app.component.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './app.component.scss' in 'D:\tutorials\ps-angular-material\src\app'
ERROR in ./src/app/contactmanager/contactmanager-app.component.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './contactmanager-app.component.scss' in 'D:\tutorials\ps-angular-material\src\app\contactmanager'
ERROR in ./src/app/contactmanager/components/...```

Comment: Well, I actually used the upload functionality of github to get the code there, but I didn't know github refuses empty files that way and some of the .scss files were empty. So I fixed that issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### in mat-sort-header you have to pass json key on which you want sort for example mat-sort-header="emp"

Comment: Thank you, as I said, I was following the course in a different (newer) version of angular and angular material and in the course, the author doesn't name the property to sort explicity and his sorting was working, even though the naming difference. But since Angular 6, for some reason (perhaps preventing magic code), the names must be equal else sorting doesn't work anymore. After rechecking the comments on pluralsight, someone else stated the same issue as well and appearently I missed it he first time.